# Call OCaml from Vim: cannot load shared library dllbin_prot_stubs

Tags: vim, ocaml, opam

I have an OCaml program that I'd like to call from Vim.

In my `.vimrc`, I have defined a command that should execute the OCaml bytecode:

```
command! MyCommand call FunctionCallingOCaml()
function! FunctionCallingOCaml()
  let scriptPath = $HOME . "/path/to/myOCamlProgram.byte"
  let ocamlCmd = "ocamlrun " . scriptPath
  execute "!" . ocamlCmd
endfunction
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work; I get an error message:

> Fatal error: cannot load shared library dllbin_prot_stubs
>   Reason: dllbin_prot_stubs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I can execute `myOCamlProgram.byte` without a hitch from another terminal running bash.

Also, I can call shell built-ins like `ls` and programs like `grep` from Vim without a problem using `execute`.

---

My system:

`uname -a`:

> Linux marathon 4.12.10-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 30 12:18:42 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`opam --version`: 1.2.2

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 19 2017 13:59:47)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that OPAM wasn't properly initialized in the shell running Vim.
The PATH didn't include the OCaml binaries which led to the error.

As a fix, I called `eval $(opam config env)` to set environment variables and modify the PATH so my Linux installation will run OCaml programs from Vim:

```
let ocamlCmd = "eval $(opam config env) && ocamlrun " . scriptPath
execute "!" . ocamlCmd
```

Better still, add this to your `.bash_profile` so your shell is initialzed with regards to OPAM every time you log in:

```
. /home/mb/.opam/opam-init/init.sh
```

The dot before the shell script [sources](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell) it.